# Node get the first element in array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to do some relations between my schemas and I have some problems with my solution.

user schema:

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type:String, default:null },
    gender: { type:String, default:null },
    role: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role', required: true },
});
```

role schema:

```
let roleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type:String, default:"Player" },
    privileges:
        [
            {
                resource: String ,
                actions: [ String ]
            },
        ],

});
```

and my query is

```
User.find({ "email":email }).populate({path: 'role', model: 'Role'}).limit(1).exec().
 then(results => {
                if (results.length) {
                    user = results[0];
                    console.log(user.role.privileges);
                }
                else {
                    throw new APIError("login_failed");
                }
            })
```

I need to access to the first element of privileges and Thank you.

Comment: I need to access to the first element of privileges of user was selected

Comment: what is coming on results[0].role.privileges[0]  .... have you console that?

Comment: when I put console.log(user.role.privileges[0]); i got this { '0': 
   { resource: 'login',
     _id: 5a1d71999001f10aad80bf50,
     actions: [ 'true' ] },
  actions: [] }

Comment: user.role.privileges[0].resource

Comment: I get this undefined

Comment: It appears your role schema doesn't match the actual structure of the documents in the roles collection. Can you update your question with a sample document from the roles collection?

Comment: {
"privileges" : 
 [
   {
     "resource" : "login" ,
     "actions": ["true"]
   }
 ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter returned by Mongoose (and Node in general) is not your data. It's the error (if any). You need to write `then( (error, results) => {`

> I need to access to the first element of privileges

`privileges` being an array, simply access the first element using :

`user.role.privileges[0]`

As an aside, you can also use Mongoose's `.findOne()` method, instead of `.find().limit(1)` :

```
User
    .findOne({ email }) // Shorthand for { email : email }
    .populate({path: 'role', model: 'Role'})
    .exec()
    .then( (error, user) => {
        if(error || !user) throw new APIError("login_failed");
        console.log(user.role.privileges[0]);
    })
```

Comment: when I put console.log(user.role.privileges[0]); i got this { '0': 
   { resource: 'login',
     _id: 5a1d71999001f10aad80bf50,
     actions: [ 'true' ] },
  actions: [] }

Comment: I need to access to resource

Comment: then you must log `user.role.privileges[0].0.resource`, But that is a pretty fragile way of acessing what you want, so consider modifying the query

Comment: I just gave you one.

Comment: Jeremy provides solution , it is better to modify query

Comment: ^_^ not jQuery ... its Jeremy Thille

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about :D

Comment: Although it is not working for you but @JeremyThille approach is correct